# Update jQuery plugin settings after init

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've searched over the SO and can't get mine plugin to update correctly. I set the plugin options upon init but i need to change the values of each setting afterwards and re-run the plugin. Here is what i have so far:

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.testPlugin = function (options) {
      // Default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            padding: '0',
            margin: '0'
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
         $(this).css({
           'padding' : settings.padding,
            'margin' : settings.margin
          });
        });
    }
}(jQuery));

// Initialize the plugin
$('#main').testPlugin({
  padding: '20px',
  margin: '20px 0'
});

// Update the plugin settings with new values and change the padding/margin on click
$('#update').on('click', function() {
  var newPadding = $('#newPadding').val();
  var newMargin = $('#newMargin').val();
  console.log(newPadding, newMargin)
  
  // Here is where i'm stuck.
  // How to update the plugin settings and re-run it?
  
})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 300px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dummy text</p>
</div>

<input type="text" id="newPadding" value="20px" />
<input type="text" id="newMargin" value="20px 0" />
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried running it the same way you initialized it?

```
$('#main').testPlugin({
  padding: newPadding,
  margin: newMargin
});
```

Comment: I guess not :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin doesn't really do anything that would have any use for updated settings, if you wanted to reset the CSS values to something else, you'd just call your plugin one more time with some other values.

If you did have a plugin that used the settings for something where they could be updated, you'd have to create some sort of system where the first argument is checked, and the settings set accordingly etc.

This is somewhat close to how jQuery UI does it when you update settings

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.testPlugin = function(options, value) {
    if (typeof options === 'string' && value) {
      this.data(options, value);
    } else {
      var opts = $.extend({
      text: 'This is a default text !'
    }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
          console.log($(this).data('text'));
        })
      }).data(opts);
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
/* ------------------------------- */
// Initialize the plugin
$('#main').testPlugin({
  text: 'This works just fine'
});

// change the setting
$('#change').on('click', function() {
  $('#main').testPlugin('text', 'So does this !');
  /*  ----  */
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
  $('#main').text('Click me again!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">Click me !</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<button id="change">Now change the text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, +1.